# Mozilla Calc isn't working

Tags: css, firefox, calc

I do have the following code to specify `image` height inside of carousel:

```
height: calc(calc(100vh / 1.6) - 34px);
```

When I inspect the object in mozilla it simply doesn't load/"see" this property.

Comment: Have you tried without the second calc, just brackets? Like `calc((100vh / 1.6) - 34px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked on Chrome, and is removes the nested calc call. Possibly mozilla doesn't automatically correct the mistake.

Try changing your css to :

`height: calc((100vh / 1.6) - 34px);`